# How can I hang a ceiling fan with a 3/4 inch difference between the junction box and bracket?

Tags: electrical, ceiling, ceiling-fan, brackets, extension

I've taken down an old ceiling fan for replacement and found the octagonal junction box to be approx 3/4in above the ceiling, it isn't flush with the drywall which the new ceiling fan bracket mount requires.

I've searched everywhere for a 3/4in deep octagonal extension and can't seem to locate one.  The shallowest extension I've found is 1 1/2in which is too deep.  The building is old and I don't feel comfortable taking down the old junction box because there are many other wires running through it other than hot and neutral that supply the fan.

Is there something I can pick up or buy online that can make up the 3/4in difference?  I know I should just use an extension, the problem is I can't find one that is 3/4in deep.

Comment: please post some photos of the ceiling situation and the fan bracket.

Answer (score 4):

There is a 3/4" extender sold by [Cooper Industries](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/crousehinds/commercial-products/catalog-pdfs/steel-octagon-boxes-covers-accessories.pdf) (and maybe others). They call it a cover. [This site](http://www.guardiancatalog.com/Cooper-Crouse-Hinds-TP331-p/04946596.htm) sells it and it probably can be found elsewhere online.

You need to be sure that the box in the ceiling is firmly attached to the framing, preferably directly screwed into a joist. Fan rated boxes have heavier duty attachments for the fan hanger and use longer screws.

Then you need to make sure that the fan hanger is firmly attached.  I would attach it directly to the ceiling box, not just the extender/cover.

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver